# Keep keyboard from automatically popping up on launch with adjustResize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keyboard

Whenever I start the app, the soft input automatically pops up since it detects a edittext on the screen. Now I am aware that a method in order to prevent this from happening would be to include `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` into the manifest. However, my application relies on windowSoftInputMode being set to adjustResize. Is there any way in which I could prevent the popping up while still keeping adjustResize? Has anyone stumbled over the problem yet?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below lines to your parent layout in `.xml` file.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to be the correct solution and is working!